# videojs disable full screen on double click

Tags: fullscreen, video.js

I want to completely disable full screen functionality.
I removed fullscreen button like this.

```
videojs('videoPlayer', {
            controlBar: {
                fullscreenToggle: false
            }
        });
```

But on double click it still goes to full screen.
How to disable double click?

Answer (score 3):

As of Video.js 7.5.0, there is an an option to turn it off directly

```
videojs("my-player", {
    userActions: {
        doubleClick: false
    }
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Darius Oleskevicius helped me with the answer on videojs github page: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/5604

The current `dblclick` handler doesn't take into consideration whether fullscreen toggle is disabled. It is on by default and there is currently no settable option to disable it. As of now, you could try and cancel out `dblclick` listener on tech (see below).

```
player.ready(function() {
 player.tech_.off('dblclick');
});
```

Also if you use reset function, you have to again remove `dblclick` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to initialize the various control-bar objects
to exist or not.

See, for example:  https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2507

So, for your case, just use:

```css
<style>
      .video-js .vjs-fullscreen-control { display: none; }
</style>
```

EDIT:

Ok, I figured out what's up with the "double-click" !

I still run all my video pages, using version 5 of videojs.
Version 5.11.9, to be exact.

And, it turns out that double-clicking on a video back then, did NOTHING.

So, bottom line, if you truly 'want to disable 'double-click-to-fullscreen',
it can be done.  Just use 5.x, rather than 6.x or 7.x

Having said all that, I now have to consider this a bug in 7.x (and 6.x).
The code inside videojs SHOULD be testing whether the fullscreen-control 
exists or not, and if not, the double-click should NOT be going to fullscreen.

The list of versions is here:   https://github.com/videojs/video.js/releases

Comment: Hi @Dave . If you read question I was able to hide button from control-bar. I just want to disable full-screen on double click.

Comment: Yes, I tried to incorporate the dbl-click, but I couldn't duplicate that part.  What are you dbl-clicking on?  (I assumed you meant 'anywhere on the player-screen, but that does nothing on mine.)

Comment: Ok, I figured out what's happening.  Just use version 5.11.9 of videojs, and double-click will be 'disabled'!

Comment: Hello @Dave. You suggest to use older version. But I want to us newest one. I agree that this is a bug. But we have to find solution for new version. Thanks.

Comment: Wise old software guru say:  "The oldest version of a product will have the fewest bugs."  He also say: "The only reason to want/need a newer version is when there is some new feature in more recent version that is needed"

Answer (score 0):

Just I added controlsList="nofullscreen" attribute. But playing the video on click on the center of  won't work. So I added onclick="vd.play()" attribute. `<video id="vd" src="video.mp4" onclick="vd.play()" disablePictureInPicture controls controlsList="nofullscreen"></video>`